# Understanding fitted function in binomial model with brms package

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I've a question regarding the fitted values of a binomial model using the `brms` package. I have this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rethinking)
data(UCBadmit)
d <- UCBadmit
detach(package:rethinking)
library(brms)
rm(UCBadmit)

d <- 
    d %>%
    mutate(male = ifelse(applicant.gender == "male", 1, 0))

m10.6 <- brm(admit | trials(applications) ~ 1 + male, data = d, family = binomial,
             prior = c(set_prior("normal(0, 10)", class = "Intercept"),
                       set_prior("normal(0, 10)", class = "b")),
             iter = 2500, warmup = 500, cores = 2, chains = 2)
```

This is implementing the following model:

[image: Binomial Model]

When I ran `head(predict(m10.6))`, I get the following table, which are the results of the summary statistics from computing `rbinom(length_of_chain, number_of_applications, invlogit(evaluation_m10.6_per_chain_value))`, i.e. summarising the samples from the first line in the model.

```
head(predict(m10.6))

      Estimate Est.Error 2.5%ile 97.5%ile
[1,] 367.45325 16.026807     336      398
[2,]  32.83225  4.899144      24       43
[3,] 249.29800 13.106969     223      275
[4,]   7.56750  2.329657       3       12
[5,] 144.88200  9.530466     126      164
[6,] 180.04175 12.949901     154      205
```

However, when I ran `fitted(predict(m10.6))`, the results are the following, but I cannot understand how these estimated errors and percentiles are computed.

```
fitted(predict(m10.6))

       Estimate Est.Error    2.5%ile   97.5%ile
[1,] 367.289295 7.9252189 352.243511 382.861665
[2,]  32.741944 1.1580285  30.418559  34.980130
[3,] 249.311521 5.3795425 239.098625 259.881858
[4,]   7.579154 0.2680622   7.041333   8.097252
[5,] 144.689722 3.1220559 138.762595 150.824292
[6,] 179.777528 6.3584342 167.020420 192.066827
```

Any explanation on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Paul-Christian Bürkner](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/), author of the `brms` package:

> `fitted()` returns posterior samples (or their summaries) of the
>   expected values of the response, which is `N * p` in case of the
>   binomial distribution. `predict()` returns posterior samples (or their
>   summaries) of the response values itself. The difference in the
>   percentiles is really that the latter incorporates variance induced by
>   sampling response values from the response distribution.